# why is <br /> different from <br></br> in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

Here's the complete source of an HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
one<br>
two<br />
three<br></br>
four    
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain why an extra blank line appears between the "three" and the "four" when I view the page in IE8 or chrome?

I thought standards were supposed to make all browsers look the same and as far as I can see this page conforms to the XHTML transitional standard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because <strike>the XHTML spec</strike> HTML Compatability Guidelines specify that `br` <strike>must</strike> should be self closing. Apparently Chrome and IE8 are not follwing the spec and closing the open one for you, thus creating a second line break.

Comment: The XHTML spec doesn't require any element to be self-closing. That is the HTML Compatibility Guidelines.

Comment: Wow, thanks - I'd always thought that XHTML specified br must be self closing.

Comment: Chrome and IE8 are following the spec — the HTML spec. This is the problem with pretending XHTML is HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this and to Alohci. I was really surprised to find this, and a bit shocked that even the latest standards have legacy stuff like this in. The reason my HTML comes out like this is because I am using ASP.NET to create a "br" element inside the control tree which seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to do. instead I'll just have to create a text node with the text "<br>" inside it - how smelly :-(

Comment: I'd use a Literal and set the text to <br/> -that's probably the cleanest way.

Answer (score 8):

Some good answers already, but just to point out that HTML5 actually *specifies* that `<br></br>` should be parsed as two `<br>` start tags when parsing as text/html.

See `An end tag whose tag name is "br"` in http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#parsing-main-inbody

Firefox 3.x only does this in quirks mode, but Firefox 4 does this in Standards mode as well.

Comment: +1 For the references. However ... 'An end tag whose tag name is "br": Parse error. Act as if a start tag token with the tag name "br" had been seen. Ignore the end tag token.' -- I'm not reading it the same way :-/

Comment: +1 ditto. @pst it means "replace `</br>` with `<br></br>` then discard the `</br>`", which basically means "interpret `</br>` as `<br>`". Thus the HTML code `<br></br>` *MUST* be interpreted as `<br><br>`.

Answer (score 5):

Although [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2), this is highly unusual code. What is much more likely is developers mistakenly using `<br>` or `</br>` when they mean `<br/>`. For this reason most browsers will interpret both as `<br/>`.

Comment: I don't understand the "for this reason" bit. It seems most logical that `</br>` would simply be ignored. (But are browsers even reasonable?)

Comment: A browser's job isn't to conform to standards, it is to display webpages. Often these will have errors, and a browser that breaks the rules to deal with these errors rather than failing is a better browser IMO.

Comment: I cannot agree. That thinking has, unfortunately, has led to the "mess" we're jut starting to come out of. It just seems that if `<br>` *was* a BR then any `</br>` could/would just be ignored -- e.g. *point* of BR was open-tag only (contents of element are irrelevant). I am kind of disappointed this case has been left in HTML5.

Comment: Interesting point, but I'd say that in this case, the chances of anyone using `<br></br>` are so slim (compared to the chance someone did it in error) that you'd piss off more people interpreting it as a single `<br/>` than as two.

Comment: the chances of anyone manually coding it as 2 separate tags are low, but (see my note above) I am using asp.net to generate a br element in the control tree. i guess you could argue it's a bug in asp.net but since there will be an increasing number of people using XML tools to generate XHTML web pages, I am definitely on the side of pst in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The extra line between three and four is because there are two `<br />` tags between them. The first one moves content onto the next line and the second one moves it one more line down. This is expected behaviour.

**Edit** Sorry, thought it was strict for the following.
Also, `<br />` tags are empty tags and so, must be closed. Because of this, I don't think that `<br>` is technically xhtml compliant. It should be `<br />`.

Comment: It is technically XHTML compliant.

Comment: @David Dorward, as I said in my edit, I was thinking of [strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6). Go [here](http://validator.w3.org/check) and try to validate this based on xhtml strict (has to be in a body tag): `<p><br></p>`

Answer (score 1):

I.E appears to interpret 
 and  both as "link break" and adds a like break for each.

Answer (score 1):

In XHTML — they are the same — and if you serve the document as `application/xhtml+xml` there will be no difference in browsers (assuming the browser supports XHTML, which IE 8 and lower do not).

If you serve the document as `text/html`, it will be treated as HTML, not XHTML, and in HTML `<br>` is an element where the end tag is forbidden. If you include an explicit end tag then some browsers will error correct to assume that `</br>` is a `<br>` *start* tag.

There are various additional rules that must be followed if you are claiming your XHTML is text/html. These are described in the [compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_1). This particular one is for [elements that can never have content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2).

Serving as text/html was a hack intended to be a short term measure during the transition to XHTML proper. Various things (including lack of support from Microsoft) prevented this transition from ever finishing, and the HTML 5 movement has given up on the idea and moved back to optional and forbidden end tags (but adding in `/>` as syntactic sugar).

Comment: I'm loading the document from a local file in this case, but I tried adding the header line

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml"/>`

and it doesn't seem to have made any difference

Comment: Dealing with local files, browsers tend to care about file extensions. `.html` Vs. `.xhtml`. Browsers **never** care about the media type specified in meta http-equiv (they sometimes care about the charset, but never the media type).