# center tag not centering in IE7

Tags: html, css

i have this code and tried a few things but nothing wants to centre it in IE7?? all is ok with chrome and FF

```
<div id='div_phone_big'></div>
<div id='div_longgray_gradient'>
<form>
   <table class='menu_bar_table' width='100%'>
     <br></br>
     <tr>
     <center>
        <span class='spn_big_lightblue_rbc'>RAINBOW</span><span class='spn_big_black_rbc'>CODE</span>
     </center>
     </tr>
     <br></br>
     <tr>
     <center>
        <span class='spn_med_yellow_rbc' >THANK YOU,YOUR FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED</span>
     </center>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

the two span tags have no alignment set in the CSS

what am i doing wrong please?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use center tag, it's deprecated. Use CSS instead. You can do something like this:

```
<td style="text-align:center">data</td>
```

You forgot to add  tag inside your . If you want to study the anatomy of a table go here http://w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
<tr> 
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <span class='spn_big_lightblue_rbc'>RAINBOW</span>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <span class='spn_big_black_rbc'>CODE</span> 
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
        <span class='spn_med_yellow_rbc' style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">THANK YOU,YOUR FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED</span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, don't use table for layout. Table is intended for tabular data, use CSS instead.

Comment: margin:auto; is for block elements. To center span you must apply text-align:center; to its parent.

Comment: im afraid non of the above worked??? i dont unserstand?
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
         <span class='spn_big_lightblue_rbc'>RAINBOW</span><span class='spn_big_black_rbc'>CODE</span>
   </tr>
   <br></br>
   <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <span class='spn_med_yellow_rbc' style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">THANK YOU,YOUR FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED</span>
   </tr>


please help? thank you

Answer (score 3):

Things you're doing wrong:

- You must have a `td` inside each `tr`: `<tr><td> .. </td></tr>`.
- Using `<center>` is bad - it's deprecated. You should be instead using `margin: 0 auto`, or `text-align: center` for inline content.
- Using tables for layout: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)
- `<br></br>` is not correct. Use `<br />` instead: [why is <br /> different from <br></br> in XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006867/why-is-br-different-from-br-br-in-xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I think that you can't use `<center>` inside a `<tr>`.

Instead, use either the `align` attribute for the `tr`, or use CSS to center it

```
<tr align="center">
  <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr style="text-align: center;>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

tag doesn't center when some of his children uses the "float" property.
Good Luck!